# need to see if column is full of zeroes or not

Tags: excel, formula

In this example, there's three users.

```
Users Apples   
Bob  
Bob   4   
Jim   
Jim  
Sim  
Sim   
Sim
```

I'd like to see if who has any apples and be able to fit that in a If formula (say if it's true or not).

I've thought about vlookup, but I'm not sure how to go about it since the value can be anything as long as it's not zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for SUMIF:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"Bob",B:B)
```

This works for numeric values in column B.  If the value can by "anything" (like text, or alphanumeric), you will probably need a different formula, like so:

```
=INDEX(B2:B7,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2:A7="Bob")*(B2:B7<>""),),0))
```